# Curl works but urllib doesn't

Tags: python, parsing, curl

Whenever I curl [this](http://www.economist.com/blogs/schumpeter/2014/04/alstom-block), I'm able to get the entire webpage. However, when I use the `urllib` or even mechanize library in Python, I get a `403 error`. Any reason why?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code

Comment: I can `GET` that URL with `urllib`, `urllib2` and `urllib3` just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
site= "http://www.economist.com/blogs/schumpeter/2014/04/alstom-block"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup
```

Output:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
....
...
..
```

Comment: Do you mean that the UserAgent was the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `requests` lib:

```
import requests
print requests.get('http://www.economist.com/blogs/schumpeter/2014/04/alstom-block').text
```